# Validate attachment in browser enabled infopath form

Tags: infopath, validation, infopath-rules, infopath-form, browser-enabled-form

I have a browser enabled Infopath form and in that there is an option to upload attachments. I want to restrict the attachments to be `jpg/` jpeg only.

Is it possible to resolve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[official documentation by Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-file-attachment-control-8e8e102f-fad5-4440-bc28-d28944f85287)** for attachment control in InfoPath:

> If you are designing a browser-compatible form template, you won't be able to specify which file types are allowed in the file attachment control.

Also,

> By default, users can attach any type of file to the form, except files such as `.exe` files, which InfoPath blocks for security reasons. To limit the types of files that users can attach to their forms, do the following:
>
> 1. Double-click the file attachment control.
> 2. Click the **Data** tab.
> 3. Under **Binding**, click **Specify default file**, and then click Browse.
> 4. In the **Attach File** dialog box, select the file that you want to appear inside the file attachment box on the form template, and then click **Insert**.

You can read more about how to add file attachment in InfoPath form using above link.

Also, you can read more about it in answer given on MSDN forum at [InfoPath - Attachment File Type Validation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9ec3784-347c-4613-8bfe-4c3686a88007/infopath-attachment-file-type-validation) which says,

> As you had known, if you are designing a **browser-compatible form template**, you won't be able to specify which file types are allowed in the file attachment control.
>
> In other words, if you create an InfoPath form using "Blank Form (InfoPath Filler) template", you will have that checkbox.